# Drupal themes don't work

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I successfully installed drupal on my localhost. I can login and post things on the website, but whenever I try new template almost nothing changes. Whole page color is white and all links are blue. Themes show no effect. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clear caches**.

On /admin/config/development/performance click the "Clear All caches" button. If you have installed the [admin_menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module you can do this easier with a link under the top left icon with the title "Flush all caches".